# C++ / cv::Mat equivalent of creating IplImage using memcpy

Tags: c++, opencv

I was handed some code where an IplImage is created using memcpy and then converted to a cv::Mat:

```
IplImage* iplImage = cvCreateImage(cv::Size(imageWidth, imageHeight), IPL_DEPTH_8U, bytesPerPixel);
memcpy(iplImage->imageData, memory, imageWidth * imageHeight * bytesPerPixel);
cv::Mat image = cv::cvarrToMat(iplImage, true, true, 0);
cvReleaseImage(&iplImage);
```

memory is a void pointer to the beginning of a memory block.

I want to port this code to use only the OpenCV C++ Api. This is what I tried first:

```
cv::Mat image(cv::Size(imageWidth, imageHeight), CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U, bytesPerPixel), memory);
```

But the image is empty.

Then I tried this:

```
cv::Mat image(cv::Size(imageWidth, imageHeight), CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U, bytesPerPixel));
memcpy(image.data, memory, imageWidth * imageHeight * bytesPerPixel);
```

This method works, however it uses up a lot more RAM (about 100mb), so I guess there is some unnecessary copying involved.

What would be the correct way to do this?

EDIT: Memory is really in a wrapper class. It gets deallocated automatically. I changed it to just "memory" for simplicity.

EDIT2: Here is the complete code, including the object the memory comes from:

```
cv::Mat RecordingPlayer::next() {
    if (currentContainer.getDataType() == odcore::data::image::SharedImage::ID()) {
        odcore::data::image::SharedImage sharedImage = currentContainer.getData<odcore::data::image::SharedImage>();
        std::shared_ptr<odcore::wrapper::SharedMemory> memory = odcore::wrapper::SharedMemoryFactory::attachToSharedMemory(sharedImage.getName());
        IplImage* iplImage = cvCreateImage(imageSize(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, bytesPerPixel);
        memcpy(iplImage->imageData, memory->getSharedMemory(), imageWidth * imageHeight * bytesPerPixel);
        cv::Mat image = cv::cvarrToMat(iplImage, true, true, 0);
        cvReleaseImage(&iplImage);
        return image;
    } else {
        return cv::Mat();
    }
}
```

Comment: After your first try, did you deallocate `memory`?

Comment: No. memory is wrapped in a weird SharedMemory object, which is wrappen in a std::shared_ptr

Comment: Could you make up a [mcve] with some dummy data in `memory`? So it will be easier to find the problem. Your first try is the correct approach, the problem seems to be in your shared object

Comment: So, just to be sure, `memory` gets automatically deallocated while your image is still valid? Probably yes

Comment: I agree. However, the problem is that the data comes from another library I don't have much documentation about. I don't really know what the data looks like, and so far as I can see there is no possibility to just create such an object with dummy data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that data in `memory->getSharedMemory()` are deallocated while the matrix is still valid.

OpenCV creates a matrix header on the underlying data, but doesn't have control over it. So you need to make a deep copy of those underlying data. Easiest way is to use `clone()`:

```
cv::Mat image = Mat(cv::Size(imageWidth, imageHeight), CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U, bytesPerPixel), memory->getSharedMemory()).clone();
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot! And it doesn't use the extra memory version 2 does. But I have to admit, I don't get why. I would have thought that memcpy and cloning the Mat would do more or less the same.

Comment: I can't give you a detailed explanation on this (I should run a few tests and check source code...), but in general OpenCV is pretty clever in memory management and optimizations, so using OpenCV functions is in general better than naive implementation. You could ask a new question about this (removing all stuff specific to your case). That will be interesting